# What is the definition or nature of “trial” in 1 Peter 1:6?

Tags: greek, 1-peter

**Q: What does Peter mean by “trial”, and what is the nature of it?**

> “Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who according
> to His great mercy has caused us to be born again to a living hope
> through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,
>
> to obtain an inheritance which is imperishable and undefiled and will
> not fade away, reserved in heaven for you, who are protected by the
> power of God through faith for a salvation ready to be revealed in the
> last time.
>
> In this you greatly rejoice, even though now for a little while, ***if
> necessary, you have been distressed by various trials***,
>
> so that the proof of your faith, being more precious than gold which
> is perishable, even though tested by fire, may be found to result in
> praise and glory and honor at the revelation of Jesus Christ;” ‭‭1
> Peter‬ ‭1:3-7‬

I am super confused about “**trials**”… “testing” by God seems more easy for me to understand.  What does a “trial” look like?  Who can be involved? Did Job go through trials?  Etc.  (**Main question is bolded up top^**)

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent word in 1 Peter 1:6 is πειρασμός (peirasmos) for which BDAG has the following entry of two meanings:

1. **an attempt to learn the nature of character of something, *test, trial***, eg, 1 Peter 4:12, 1:6, James 1:2, Heb 3:8
2. **an attempt to make one do something wrong, *temptation, enticement*** to sin, eg, Luke 4:13, Matt 6:13, Luke 11:4, etc.

Obviously, the first meaning is what we need in 1 Peter 1:6.  That is, the "trials" that peter alludes to do what Peter is saying they are used for - to test and prove the character of the individual through the fire-refining process

> 1 Peter 1:7 - so that the proven character of your faith—more precious
> than gold, which perishes even though refined by fire—may result in
> praise, glory, and honor at the revelation of Jesus Christ.

Barnes offers this comment:

> Through many kinds of trials, ... The meaning here is, that they now
> endured many things which were suited to try or test their faith.
> These might have consisted of poverty, persecution, sickness, or the
> efforts of others to lead them to renounce their religion, and to go
> back to their former state of unbelief. Anyone or all of these would
> try them, and would show whether their religion was genuine. On the
> various ways which God has of trying his people, compare the notes at
> Isaiah 28:23-29.

Note a parallel piece of advice from James 1:2-4

> Consider it pure joy, my brothers, when you encounter trials of many
> kinds, because you know that the testing of your faith develops
> perseverance. Allow perseverance to finish its work, so that you may
> be mature and complete, not lacking anything.

If Christians never endured trials and hardships, no character would be developed.

Comment: That certainly clears things up, +1.